# Javascript Send Virtual Click to Calendar Not Working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

At my work, we use a custom web app that has a date picker/calendar that I am trying to programmatically change.  The program is written in Vue if that helps.  I've tried everything imaginable to actually select the date or inject the date and nothing seems to work.  I can select the buttons like so:

`element = document.querySelector("#__BVID__2692__cell-2023-08-05_")`

But when I run element.click(), nothing happens.  I've tried sending customEvents to it and no luck.  Even more annoying is that it has previous year/month and next year/month buttons that I can click just fine, but the actual days themselves remain unclickable.  Obviously, I can click with my mouse and it works just fine. Looking at Vue examples online, it appears to be a pretty standard datepicker from Vue. This is what it looks like in app.  Any insight or guidance would be appreciated.

[image]

Also, when I select a number, this is what it looks like:

`<div id="__BVID__2692__cell-2023-08-01_" role="button" data-date="2023-08-01" aria-label="Tue, Aug 01, 2023" class="col p-0"><span class="btn border-0 rounded-circle text-nowrap btn-outline-light text-dark font-weight-bold">1</span></div>`

I'm guessing that the 'role=button' part is the problem since this isn't an actual button.  However, it has to work somehow since mouse clicks do work.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  I used the Elements tab to look at what listeners were attached and found that listener was actually attached to the span object.  I selected that and clicked and it worked like a charm.